# VSIX Installer: SignatureDescription could not be created for the signature algorithm supplied

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vsix, productivity-power-tools

## Unable to install Productivity Power Tools Extension for Visual Studio Professional 2015 RC

1. Visual Studio IDE, Tools > Extensions and Updates > Online > Visual Studio gallery
2. [`visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com`](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d) site.

[image: SignatureDescription could not be created for the signature algorithm supplied.]

`Install Log`

```
2015-07-22 8:22:27 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
2015-07-22 8:22:27 AM - -------------------------------------------
2015-07-22 8:22:27 AM - Initializing Install...
2015-07-22 8:22:28 AM - Extension Details...
2015-07-22 8:22:28 AM -     Identifier      : VSProPack.Microsoft.15893CD4-2422-4427-BEA8-4E28DCC26346
2015-07-22 8:22:28 AM -     Name            : Productivity Power Tools 2015
2015-07-22 8:22:28 AM -     Author          : Microsoft
2015-07-22 8:22:28 AM -     Version         : 14.0.23120.0
2015-07-22 8:22:28 AM -     Description     : A set of extensions to Visual Studio 2015 Community (and above) which improves developer productivity.
2015-07-22 8:22:28 AM -     Locale          : en-US
2015-07-22 8:22:28 AM -     MoreInfoURL     : http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=618589
2015-07-22 8:22:28 AM -     InstalledByMSI  : False
2015-07-22 8:22:28 AM -     SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5,)
2015-07-22 8:22:28 AM - 
2015-07-22 8:22:28 AM - System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: SignatureDescription could not be created for the signature algorithm supplied.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignedInfo(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignature(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignature(X509Certificate2 certificate, Boolean verifySignatureOnly)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.XmlDigitalSignatureProcessor.Verify(X509Certificate2 signer)
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackageDigitalSignature.Verify(X509Certificate signingCertificate)
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackageDigitalSignature.Verify()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.InstallableExtensionImpl.GetSignatureState(ZipPackage vsixPackage)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.InstallableExtensionImpl.get_SignatureState()
   at VSIXInstaller.App.LogExtensionDetails(IExtension extension)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer after scanning through the description section again:

> Productivity Power Tools 2015 can not be installed on the RC version of VS 2015.
>
> NOTE:
>
> This version is signed in a manner which is not supported by the **RC** version of Visual Studio 2015. It will only install on the **RTM** version. You can download the RTM version of Visual Studio 2015 [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs) - the Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition and higher support the installation of Productivity Power Tools and other Visual Studio Extensions.

Comment: could one somehow bypass this? for example this might give a clue: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2013/01/21/signaturedescription-could-not-be-created-for-the-signature-algorithm-supplied.aspx

Comment: found a solution, see my separate reply

Answer (score 0):

Try installing
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=619615
(found from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2015/07/29/building-apps-for-windows-10-with-visual-studio-2015.aspx)

I used Custom installation option and selected everything. It upgraded Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise RC to Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and now those extensions that had started recently to not install, are installing fine. That way you'll avoid the trouble of reinstalling everything.

Note that after installation finishes it shows a button to Launch Visual Studio, which will launch the Enterprise edition (or Professional in the case I guess one had Professional RC installed). However your Windows taskbar shortcuts for Visual Studio 2015 and Blend 2015 will be now broken and you have to fix them by right-clicking them and selecting Properties, then setting them to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe and C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\blend.exe respectively, assuming you use an 64-bit OS - else remove the “ (x86)” part - and had installed Visual Studio on C: disk. You may wish to also add those links to the Start menu, under the respective folder (named Visual Studio 2015) if you also miss them from there.